# Qt Android QGraphicsscene->AddPixmap does not work properly

Tags: android, c++, qt

I working on a project that listing an order from citizen include text and images.

I have encountered an awesome problem that Qgraphicsscene->addPixmap, sometimes works and sometimes it does not. I cannot detect what problem is.

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pItem;    
pItem = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

img is loaded properly and tested if it did not loaded.

When I Run Application Qt Creator output Below:

```
Starting remote process.E/Zygote  (23262): MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote  (23262): v2
I/SELinux (23262): Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-A500F_4.4.4 ver=46
I/SELinux (23262): Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-A500F_5.0.2-1_0039
E/SELinux (23262): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
I/libpersona(23262): KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10276
I/libpersona(23262): KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
I/ActivityManager( 1004): Start proc org.qtproject.serikbelediyesi for activity org.qtproject.serikbelediyesi/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity: pid=23262 uid=10276 gids={50276, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=armeabi-v7a
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(23262): TimaSignature is unavailable
D/ActivityThread(23262): Added TimaKeyStore provider
E/Qt      (23262): Can't create main activity
E/Qt      (23262): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/org.qtproject.serikbelediyesi/lib/libplugins_platforms_libqoffscreen.so: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/Qt      (23262):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
E/Qt      (23262):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
E/Qt      (23262):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
E/Qt      (23262):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.createBundledBinary(QtActivity.java:416)
E/Qt      (23262):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.extractBundledPluginsAndImports(QtActivity.java:489)
E/Qt      (23262):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:582)
E/Qt      (23262):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2752)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/Qt      (23262):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
E/Qt      (23262):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Qt      (23262):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/Qt      (23262):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
E/Qt      (23262):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
E/Qt      (23262): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/Qt      (23262):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
E/Qt      (23262):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
E/Qt      (23262):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
E/Qt      (23262):  ... 19 more
D/PhoneWindow(23262): *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
```

Comment: Don't know why it isn't working, but do you think a graphics scene is the right tool for displaying order information?

Comment: "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" - are you sure that it loads property?

Comment: i in the build directory that caught my attention int the lib*.so files, [libplugins_platforms_libqoffscreen.so] does not exist always. one time that exist and application run properly and show picture. otherwise not build and not working properly. ddriver is there another way to show picture to screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**yes OK, Updrage your Qt Library to Qt 5.6 Release Candidate**

I haven't found any solution yet. but i upgraded to Qt 5.6 Release Candidate, Any Problem Seeing. many times change my code and add some example code to my project, there is not any problem. `libplugins_platforms_libqoffscreen.so`
always creating and loding properly and QLabel or any QWidget show my pixmap.